# C# is there a limit to number of selected files in Open File Dialog

Tags: c#, winforms, openfiledialog

I've got a C# windows forms application where I load XML files and CGM graphics files into my application from an Open File browser. I seem to be able to select a couple of hundred at a time and it works without fault, but any more and a dialog box pops up telling me it can't find file such and such, but only gives half the file name. I'm assuming this is due to a limit on the amount of files that can be selected / processed in one go through the open file dialog.

Does anybody know what that number is, and is there a way around it if i have more than that limit to select at once?

I'm effectively 'importing' the files into my application, whereby using a foreach loop the selected files get moved to another folder, and the application writes to an XML file with all the file names of the files imported (as well as other data on the files).

Below is the entire 'import' method

```
private void addFilesToCSDBToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int DMsimported = 0;
    int graphicsImported = 0;

    if (projectName == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please open a project first", "DAWS");
        return;
    }

    DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("This process may take several minutes depending on the number of imports", "DAWS");
        Application.UseWaitCursor = true;

        foreach (string file in openFileDialog1.FileNames)
        {
            string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file); //Gets just the name from the file path
            string ext = Path.GetExtension(file.ToLower());

            if (ext != ".CGM" && ext != ".cgm")
            {
                    bool exists = xmlFileWriter.checkIfFIleExists(fileName + ext);

                    if (exists != true)
                    {
                        xmlFileWriter.writeDatatoXML(file);
                        File.Move(file, CSDBpath + projectName + "\\CheckedIN\\" + fileName + ext);
                        DMsimported = DMsimported + 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(fileName + " already exists in the CSDB. This file will be skipped.", "DAWS");
                    }  
                }
            else
            {
                if (File.Exists(CSDBpath + projectName + "\\Graphics\\" + fileName + ext))
                {
                    if (Properties.Settings.Default.OverwriteGraphics == true)
                    {
                        File.SetAttributes(CSDBpath + projectName + "\\Graphics\\" + fileName + ext, FileAttributes.Normal); // need this line in order to set the file attributes. Exception thrown otherwise when system tries to overwrite the file.
                        File.Delete(CSDBpath + projectName + "\\Graphics\\" + fileName + ext);
                        File.Copy(file, CSDBpath + projectName + "\\Graphics\\" + fileName  + ext); //need to give the option as to whether to delete the existing file or skipp.
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(fileName + " already exists in the CSDB. This file will be skipped. To enable overwriting tick the checkbox in Preferences", "DAWS");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    File.Copy(file, CSDBpath + projectName + "\\Graphics\\" + fileName + ext);
                }

                graphicsImported = graphicsImported + 1;                            
            }   
        }

        Application.UseWaitCursor = false;

        buildAllListViews();
        copyCGMfilesToDirectories();

        if (DMsimported > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(DMsimported.ToString() + " DM files successfully imported into the CSDB", "DAWS");
        }
        if (graphicsImported > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(graphicsImported.ToString() + " graphic files successfully imported into the CSDB", "DAWS");
        }
        if (graphicsImported == 0 && DMsimported == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No files imported", "DAWS");
        }

        updateMainFilesList();  
    }  
}
```

Comment: I can't imagine it would be limited to only a few hundred. I think there is something else happening. Can you reproduce with a simple program? Where does the dialog pop up? While you are selecting the files in the Windows OpenFile dialog?

Comment: Post some code how you are using the dialog.

Comment: I would not use string concatenation to create a path (where file is moved, copied, etc.), may be created path is longer that system allows it to be. Could you show exact exception and stack trace or there's no exception, but some windows message?

Comment: @Giedrius I can run in debug mode and no exceptions are thrown, just a windows message that say: "File C:\[file path] does not exist. Verify that the correct file name was given."

Comment: Could you add breakpoint before foreach loop starts? If you access that breakpoint before message shows up, I'm pretty sure, exception comes from the loop, then add try catch for whole loop and on catch add breakpoint to make sure, that it is not an exeption.

Comment: @Giedrius - i've just put a breakpoint at the 'if (result == DialogResult.OK)' line .... and the program didn't even reach that point before getting the Windoes message. What on earth does this pont towards??

Comment: hm, could you try create new windows application drop openfiledialog on it with default settings, and try open same directory where you have problem? if still have problem, create a test directory and fill with test files as I've done in my answer just to make sure, that is not some kind of permissions issue, it other words to isolate problem in smaller context.

Answer (score 3):

According to this [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/820631), you will receive a "`Too many files selected`" error message when you use the `OpenFileDialog` control to select more than `200` files.

Comment: Doesn't seem to match what the OP says though. But I think they are just not handling the exception properly so this is probably the answer.

Comment: Thanks, but i'm not getting that error. It just gives me a dialog saying that it can't find file, but only shows a portion of the file name as if it's being cut short.

Comment: @Daedalus But that might be because you aren't handling an exception correctly - can you run it under the debugger with `Debug -> Exceptions -> Common Language Runtime Exceptions -> Thrown[x]` selected?

Comment: i've just put a breakpoint at the 'if (result == DialogResult.OK)' line .... and the program didn't even reach that point before getting the Windoes message. Any ideas what this might point towards??

Comment: @Daedalus That would imply that something threw an exception before reaching that point. Did you try running under the debugger with `Thrown` exception detection turned on?

Comment: @MatthewWatson yeah i just tried that, and it did nothing different. If the exception is being thrown before the line 'if (result == DialogResult.OK)' then surely there is very little i can do to control it? It seems that the problem is in the dialog box control itself, surely?

Answer (score 3):

Just tested in .NET 4.5, no problem with 5000 files, so it looks like it depends on .net framework/os version (I've used long enough file names, just to be sure, that it does not depend on some old windows constraint, like max length of all file names is 65536 or 32768):

```
var directory = @"c:\test\test";
Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);

for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
{
    var path = Path.Combine(directory, i.ToString() + new string('a', 200));
    File.WriteAllText(path, "");
}

if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    var fileCount = openFileDialog1.FileNames;
    var lastFileName = openFileDialog1.FileNames[4999];
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, so no limit the. I'm using 4.5 too so must be something else. I've just posted some code above. would you be kind anough to have a quick look and see if there's anything fundamentally wrong there that could cause it.

Answer (score 1):

In .NET Framework 1.1, for the [OpenFileDialog.Multiselect Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.multiselect%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> There is a hard-coded limit of 200 files that can be opened with the
>   Open File dialog box. For more information about this limitation, see
>   article 820631, "PRB: 'Too Many Files Selected' Error Message Occurs
>   When You Use the OpenFileDialog Control", in the Microsoft Knowledge
>   Base at http://support.microsoft.com.

When you have to work with such a large number of files, maybe it makes more sense to select only the folder (even more reasonable if you select all the files in the folder, if this is your case). Try using the [FolderBrowserDialog Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.aspx):

```
var folderBrowserDialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
if (folderBrowserDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    var fi = new DirectoryInfo(folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath);
    // here you get the files collection
    var files = fi.GetFiles();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
   if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    openFileDialog1.Multiselect = false;
    var fileCount = openFileDialog1.FileNames;
    var lastFileName = openFileDialog1.FileNames[4999];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this does nothing, and i wouldn't expect it to as if i set a breakpoint at the 'if (result == DialogResult.OK)' line, the program doesn't even reach this point before the message pops up. So with my limited experience i'd say it's something to do with the dialog. 'DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();'