# Does OpenFileDialog have a limit to the number of files it can upload?

Tags: vb.net

does OpenFileDialog control have a restriction on the maximum number of files it can upload?
i'm curreently working on an application that uploads files to an FTP Server. the codes work perfectly to upload up to 80 files but if i try to upload more than 80 files,it says "file not found".
i want to modify the codes so it can accept any number and size of files. if OpenFileDialog can't make it happen, kindly show me an alternative. thanks
here is my codes:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Public Class FTPServerApp
    Private Sub FTPServerApp_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
    End Sub
    Private Sub btnAddFile_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddFile.Click
        Dim OpenFile As New OpenFileDialog() With {.Multiselect = True}
        If OpenFile.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            If OpenFile.FileNames.Count = 1 Then
                Dim newItm As New ListViewItem(Path.GetFileName(OpenFile.FileName))
                newItm.SubItems.Add(txtServer.Text & "/" & Path.GetFileName(OpenFile.FileName))
                newItm.SubItems.Add("")
                newItm.SubItems.Add(OpenFile.FileName)
                lstCollection.Items.Add(newItm)
            ElseIf OpenFile.FileNames.Count > 1 Then
                For Each Str As String In OpenFile.FileNames
                    If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(Str) Then
                        Dim newItm As New ListViewItem(Path.GetFileName(Str))
                        newItm.SubItems.Add(txtServer.Text & "/" & Path.GetFileName(Str))
                        newItm.SubItems.Add("")
                        newItm.SubItems.Add(Str)
                        lstCollection.Items.Add(newItm)
                    End If
                Next
            End If
            lblCount.Text = "0 /" & lstCollection.Items.Count
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub btnUploadFile_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUploadFile.Click
        bWorker.RunWorkerAsync()
    End Sub
    Private Sub bWorker_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bWorker.DoWork
        For Each itm As ListViewItem In lstCollection.Items
            Try
                Dim request As FtpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(New Uri(itm.SubItems.Item(1).Text)), FtpWebRequest)
                request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile
                request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(txtUser.Text, txtPassword.Text)
                request.UseBinary = True
                request.UsePassive = False
                Dim buffer(1023) As Byte
                Dim bytesIn As Long = 1
                Dim totalBytesIn As Long = 0
                Dim filepath As System.IO.FileInfo = New System.IO.FileInfo(itm.SubItems.Item(3).Text)
                Dim ftpstream As System.IO.FileStream = filepath.OpenRead()
                Dim flLength As Long = ftpstream.Length
                Dim reqfile As System.IO.Stream = request.GetRequestStream
                Do Until bytesIn < 1
                    bytesIn = ftpstream.Read(buffer, 0, 1024)
                    If bytesIn > 0 Then
                        reqfile.Write(buffer, 0, bytesIn)
                        totalBytesIn += bytesIn
                        If flLength > 0 Then
                            Dim perc As Integer = (totalBytesIn / flLength) * 100
                            bWorker.ReportProgress(perc, CInt(itm.Index + 1))
                        End If
                    End If
                Loop
                reqfile.Close()
                ftpstream.Close()
                itm.SubItems.Item(2).Text = "File Succesfully uploaded!"
            Catch ex As Exception
                itm.SubItems.Item(2).Text = "File was not uploaded!"
            End Try
        Next
    End Sub
    Private Sub bWorker_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles bWorker.ProgressChanged
        pBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
        lblPercent.Text = e.ProgressPercentage & " %"
        lblCount.Text = CInt(e.UserState) & " / " & lstCollection.Items.Count
    End Sub
    Private Sub bWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles bWorker.RunWorkerCompleted
        MsgBox("Finish!")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: `OpenFileDialog` doesn't *upload* files, so it has no limitations in that respect. `OpenFileDialog` gets a selection of one or more files from the user and returns them to your code, which can do whatever it wants (including uploading those files). What specific line of code is causing the *file not found* error? Is it in `DoWork`, or in the code calling it? What is the value of `OpenFileDialog.FileNames.Count`? It also appears you're removing the path portion of the name when you're adding it to the ListView. Are all the files selected in the same exact folder?

Comment: please read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16853210/c-sharp-is-there-a-limit-to-number-of-selected-files-in-open-file-dialog

Comment: Thanks Ken White for the correction and also for your contribution. i figured my way around the codes and i can upload as many files as i want. thanks